Django Table Will Not Create
I have an django app with many apps inside of it. One is a calendar model. I have tried to get this table created so many times without any response that I chose to go down the route of resetting everything. No matter how many times I reset the database or migrations, the table will not create. All other tables are completely fine. It is this sole table every time I try to migrate. I have tried many different solutions to no avail.
calendar_event/models.py
class CalendarEvents(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EVENT_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=145,null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='creator')
    guests = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    event_last_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    repeating = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    repeat_interval = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    repeat_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices= RECURRENCE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    repeat_by_weekdays = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAY_CHOICES), default=list, null=True, blank=True)
    recurrence = RecurrenceField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Recurrence")


When I run makemigrations the table shows it's understood and ready to be created, but simply does not show up

Solution Attempts

I have tried resetting all migrations (keeping the init.py file)
I have tried resetting the database and recreating from scratch
I have tried migrating from an initial state using --fake and zero in my migration commands

I have tried the above solutions 10 different ways from across different resource sites and django documentation. I feel I am overlooking something so small..
Here is my showmigrations:
account
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_initial
accounts
 (no migrations)
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices   
apps
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_initial
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length   
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length        
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length     
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length    
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length        
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length   
authtoken
 [X] 0001_initial
calendar_event
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_calendarevents_options_and_more
chat
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
djstripe
 [X] 0001_initial
layouts
 (no migrations)
recurrence
 [X] 0001_initial
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
sites
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_domain_unique
social_django
 [X] 0001_initial
socialaccount
 [X] 0001_initial
taggit
 [X] 0001_initial
tenants
 [X] 0001_initial

Directory breakdown

calendar_event is in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS

EDIT 1:
From the django shell:
Python 3.11.5 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:26:23) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from calendar_event.models import CalendarEvents
>>> CalendarEvents.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JohnV\github\lang-industries\msp-dashboard\msp-dashboard\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "calendar_events" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ncy", "calendar_events"."repeat_by_weekdays" FROM "calendar_...

DB Shell
Table is not created, string matches project, PGAdmin perfectly reflect this DB shell and project migrations



try python manage.py makemigrations --empty calendar_event and see if you become successfull

Is it possible you're running the migrations against a different database or even a different database on a different cluster from the one you're later checking this on? You might have multiple instances of Postgres running on different ports, and each can be hosting multiple databases under different names, and on each of those you could be creating these tables in a different schema/namespace.

@Zegarek I only have 1 database config within my settings. It is a PostgresSQL server on render.com. This is the only process running. It would be unusual that only this table, every single time is the only one going to that 'other' db if it existed.

@sahasrara62, nice command, I hadn't seen this one before. I tried and was still unsuccessful, table did not create

where you are checking if table created ? in db ?

I used the external connection string redner provides and connected it to my local PGAdmin @sahasrara62

refresehed ? your django projhect is correctly configured to it ? test through db shell if table created

@sahasrara62 I just edited my post with what happens in the shell - that was a good idea - looks like the class is recognized, by the actual table cannot be called. I can import the class, but cannot operate on it. psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "calendar_events" does not exist
And yes, correctly configured to Postgres. All other tables create and update completely fine anytime I migrate. It is solely this table

db shell , if after the migratiion command no eror come, check in db shell if table there

@sahasrara62 misunderstood. I posted the shell output with the connection string that matches the app and where I have the server connected via PGAdmin. Tables should be 'here' from the picture but are not. The class is understood by the app, but the tables have not been created and that is reflected in the database

Can you share the content of 0001_initial and 0002_alter_calendarevents_options_and_more file from calendar_event/migrations folder?

I am gonna throw my hat into the ring and say that the migration has failed silently. As suggested above, I would take a look at the migration file. Maybe you can try and remove the relational fields one by one (Which in that case would be most likely to cause the issue) and see if that might create the table in the db. You can also have a more detailed output when you run migrations by using --verbosity 3. Good luck!
